# Prefix each member of an xpathexpression nodelist

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I would like to construct an xpath query such that [xpathexpression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathExpression.html).evaulate returns a list of values prefixed with an arbitrary string.

Achieving this with a single result is a simple `concat('PREFIX:',/returns/one/node)`, although the valid xpath query `/returns/many/nodes/concat('PREFIX:',text())` is not accepted by [xpathexpression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathExpression.html).evaulate.

Here is my function call:

`NodeList resultNodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc,  XPathConstants.NODESET);
String collectionIDs[] = new String[resultNodes.getLength()];`

This is the error I receive:

`javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Unknown nodetype: concat`

Does anyone know of an evaluate-friendly alternative?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

That's because your "valid xpath query" isn't valid. `concat()` is a function which accepts parameters, which is why your first xpath: `concat('PREFIX:',/returns/one/node)` is being used correctly, and works.

When you place it at the end of your xpath like you did here: `/returns/many/nodes/concat('PREFIX:',text())` it's attempting to find a node type called "concat," which doesn't exist, and thus the error you received.

`expr.evaluate()` will evaluate your `concat('PREFIX:',/returns/one/node)` as a parameter, but as it is expecting a return type of nodelist, and `concat()` returns a string type, that won't work either, so you have a couple choices:

You will have to give your xpath of `/returns/many/nodes` to `evaluate()`, and then set index 0 of your `String[]` with "PREFIX:" before filling it with your XPath results.

Or

You can evaluate the `concat('PREFIX:',/returns/one/node)` xpath and change the expected type to string, but then you have one long string to deal with.